# Where to find reports of A/B testing about ways to alter beliefs about scientific facts?

Tags: experimental-psychology, education

**QUESTION**

Where can I find examples of protocols and results of A/B tests of techniques to alter one subject's belief about scientific topics (aka Educating them)?

**BACKGROUND**

A Theoretical Computer Scientist for the last 20 years, I recently started to work on automatizing psychological processes and experiments (with both humans and other animals than humans), and showing how this can lead to the expected quantitative improvements (the usual outcome of automatizing things) but also qualitative ones (automatizing processes can decrease the quality of the process output, but in some cases it results in neat qualitative improvements).

After some success automatizing some experiments with other animals than humans, I am working on proving the point above through some experiments with humans, and in particular I am thinking about designing some (automatized) A/B tests to compare (automatized) interventions to alter a subject's conviction about some scientific facts (and properties) related to [fossil fuel production peaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_oil), [greenhouse gazes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenhouse_gas), [population overshoot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overshoot_(population)).

As I did not find such studies in the existing scientific literature about such topics in journals with themes related to climate change (e.g. [Nature Climate Change](https://%20https://journals.sagepub.com/climatechange)), I assume that there is none in the existing scientific literature about changing people's belief, but I am a bit at a loss as to which journals to consult, and could anyway benefit from reviewing previous work about (not so automatized) interventions to change some subject's beliefs.